# GPA Calculator Error - Variable might not been initialized?

Tags: java, variables, command-line-interface

Can anyone please help me get through this problem ?

```
/*
author: M Asad Raza
date: 18/03/2014
*/

Code:-

import java.util.Scanner;

    class GPACalculator { 
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            double sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5,sub6,subtotal=100*6,obtained,GP;
            double gp1,gp2,gp3,gp4,gp5,gp6;
            String name;    
                System.out.println("   \n***Welcome to GPA Calculator***\n");
                System.out.print("Enter your good name: ");
                name=input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("\n**Hello "+name+" :)\n");
                System.out.print("Enter Subject#1 marks: ");
                sub1=input.nextInt();
                if(sub1>100){
                System.out.println("Marks exceeded from the limit.\nTry agian..!!");
                System.exit(0);
                }
                if(sub1<45){
                System.out.println("Subject failed!!\nGPA can't be calculated.");
                System.exit(0);
                }
                System.out.print("Enter Subject#2 marks: ");
                sub2=input.nextInt();
                if(sub2>100){
                System.out.println("Marks exceeded from the limit.\nTry agian..!!");
                System.exit(0);
                }
                if(sub2<45){
                System.out.println("Subject failed!!\nGPA can't be calculated.");
                System.exit(0);
                }
                System.out.print("Enter Subject#3 marks: ");
                sub3=input.nextInt();
                if(sub3>100){
                System.out.println("Marks exceeded from the limit.\nTry agian..!!");
                System.exit(0);
                }
                if(sub3<45){
                System.out.println("Subject failed!!\nGPA can't be calculated.");
                System.exit(0);
                }
                System.out.print("Enter Subject#4 marks: ");
                sub4=input.nextInt();
                if(sub4>100){
                System.out.println("Marks exceeded from the limit.\nTry agian..!!");
                System.exit(0);
                }
                if(sub4<45){
                System.out.println("Subject failed!!\nGPA can't be calculated.");
                System.exit(0);
                }
                System.out.print("Enter Subject#5 marks: ");
                sub5=input.nextInt();
                if(sub5>100){
                System.out.println("Marks exceeded from the limit.\nTry agian..!!");
                System.exit(0);
                }
                if(sub5<45){
                System.out.println("Subject failed!!\nGPA can't be calculated.");
                System.exit(0);
                }
                System.out.print("Enter Subject#6 marks: ");
                sub6=input.nextInt();
                if(sub6>100){
                System.out.println("Marks exceeded from the limit.\nTry agian..!!");
                System.exit(0);
                }
                if(sub6<45){
                System.out.println("Subject failed!!\nGPA can't be calculated.");
                System.exit(0);
                }

                //Calculating GPA
                if(sub1>=85&&sub1<=100) {
                gp1=4.00;
                }

                if(sub1>=80&&sub1<=84) {
                gp1=3.70;
                }
                if(sub1>=75&&sub1<=79) {
                gp1=3.30;
                }
                if(sub1>=70&&sub1<=74) {
                gp1=3.00;
                }
                if(sub1>=65&&sub1<=69) {
                gp1=2.70;
                }
                if(sub1>=60&&sub1<=64) {
                gp1=2.30;
                }
                if(sub1>=55&&sub1<=59) {
                gp1=2.00;
                }
                if(sub1>=50&&sub1<=54) {
                gp1=1.70;
                }
                if(sub1>=45&&sub1<=49) {
                gp1=1.00;
                }
                //*****sub1 gp1 finished
                if(sub2>=85&&sub2<=100) {
                gp2=4.00;
                }
                if(sub2>=80&&sub2<=84) {
                gp2=3.70;
                }
                if(sub2>=75&&sub2<=79) {
                gp2=3.30;
                }
                if(sub2>=70&&sub2<=74) {
                gp2=3.00;
                }
                if(sub2>=65&&sub2<=69) {
                gp2=2.70;
                }
                if(sub2>=60&&sub2<=64) {
                gp2=2.30;
                }
                if(sub2>=55&&sub2<=59) {
                gp2=2.00;
                }
                if(sub2>=50&&sub2<=54) {
                gp2=1.70;
                }
                if(sub2>=45&&sub2<=49) {
                gp2=1.00;
                }
                //***** sub2 gp2 finished
                if(sub3>=85&&sub3<=100) {
                gp3=4.00;
                }
                if(sub3>=80&&sub3<=84) {
                gp3=3.70;
                }
                if(sub3>=75&&sub3<=79) {
                gp3=3.30;
                }
                if(sub3>=70&&sub3<=74) {
                gp3=3.00;
                }
                if(sub3>=65&&sub3<=69) {
                gp3=2.70;
                }
                if(sub3>=60&&sub3<=64) {
                gp3=2.30;
                }
                if(sub3>=55&&sub3<=59) {
                gp3=2.00;
                }
                if(sub3>=50&&sub3<=54) {
                gp3=1.70;
                }
                if(sub3>=45&&sub3<=49) {
                gp3=1.00;
                }
                //*****sub3 gp3 finished
                if(sub4>=85&&sub4<=100) {
                gp4=4.00;
                }
                if(sub4>=80&&sub4<=84) {
                gp4=3.70;
                }
                if(sub4>=75&&sub4<=79) {
                gp4=3.30;
                }
                if(sub4>=70&&sub4<=74) {
                gp4=3.00;
                }
                if(sub4>=65&&sub4<=69) {
                gp4=2.70;
                }
                if(sub4>=60&&sub4<=64) {
                gp4=2.30;
                }
                if(sub4>=55&&sub4<=59) {
                gp4=2.00;
                }
                if(sub4>=50&&sub4<=54) {
                gp4=1.70;
                }
                if(sub4>=45&&sub4<=49) {
                gp4=1.00;
                }
                //*****gp4 sub4 finished
                if(sub5>=85&&sub5<=100) {
                gp5=4.00;
                }
                if(sub5>=80&&sub5<=84) {
                gp5=3.70;
                }
                if(sub5>=75&&sub5<=79) {
                gp5=3.30;
                }
                if(sub5>=70&&sub5<=74) {
                gp5=3.00;
                }
                if(sub5>=65&&sub5<=69) {
                gp5=2.70;
                }
                if(sub5>=60&&sub5<=64) {
                gp5=2.30;
                }
                if(sub5>=55&&sub5<=59) {
                gp5=2.00;
                }
                if(sub5>=50&&sub5<=54) {
                gp5=1.70;
                }
                if(sub5>=45&&sub5<=49) {
                gp5=1.00;
                }
                //***** sub5 gp5 finished
                if(sub6>=85&&sub6<=100) {
                gp6=4.00;
                }
                if(sub6>=80&&sub6<=84) {
                gp6=3.70;
                }
                if(sub6>=75&&sub6<=79) {
                gp6=3.30;
                }
                if(sub6>=70&&sub6<=74) {
                gp6=3.00;
                }
                if(sub6>=65&&sub6<=69) {
                gp6=2.70;
                }
                if(sub6>=60&&sub6<=64) {
                gp6=2.30;
                }
                if(sub6>=55&&sub6<=59) {
                gp6=2.00;
                }
                if(sub6>=50&&sub6<=54) {
                gp6=1.70;
                }
                if(sub6>=45&&sub6<=49) {
                gp6=1.00;
                }

                //End Calculating GPA

                obtained=sub1+sub2+sub3+sub4+sub5+sub6;
                GP=gp1+gp2+gp3+gp4+gp5+gp6;
                GP=GP/6;
                System.out.println("\n\n******Information******\n");
                System.out.println("Total Marks = "+subtotal+"\n"+"Obtained marks = "+obtained+"\n"+"Percentage = "+(obtained/subtotal)*100);
                System.out.println("GPA = "+GP);
                System.out.println("\n***********************");

        }       
    }
```

Comment: Compile time or runtime error? And what line does it occur on?

Comment: Are you sure all your `gp` variables are getting initialized? Try setting an initial value of 0 to them?

Comment: What problem? Post at least the error or unexpected behaviour you get.

Answer (score 0):

Without further knowledge ( like what the error is for example ... ) my first guess would be that this line is the culprit.

```
double sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5,sub6,subtotal=100*6,obtained,GP;
```

I think that this is setting sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5,sub6 & subtotal to 600, and leaving obtained and GP uninitialised. ( it's a very uncommon looking line of code as well )

If that's the case, then

```
double gp1,gp2,gp3,gp4,gp5,gp6;
```

is probably also leaving these variable uninitialised.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot know if your variables are initialized or not unless you either explicitly initialize them when they're declared or make sure every path in your code initializes them before they are used.

Since `0.0` doesn't seem to be a suitable default value for your variables, you should be using `if...else if...else` control statements instead of simple `if` statements.

```
//Calculating GPA
if(sub1>=85) {
    gp1=4.00;
}
else if(sub1>=80&&sub1<=84) {
    gp1=3.70;
}
else if(sub1>=75&&sub1<=79) {
    gp1=3.30;
}
else if(sub1>=70&&sub1<=74) {
    gp1=3.00;
}
else if(sub1>=65&&sub1<=69) {
    gp1=2.70;
}
else if(sub1>=60&&sub1<=64) {
    gp1=2.30;
}
else if(sub1>=55&&sub1<=59) {
    gp1=2.00;
}
else if(sub1>=50&&sub1<=54) {
    gp1=1.70;
}
else { // (sub1>=45&&sub1<=49)
    gp1=1.00; // or some other value when sub1 < 45?
}
```

Note that the compiler doesn't know at compile time that `sub1` is not allowed to be outside the range 45 - 100.  You need to be sure that `gp1` is initialized in *all possible* branches (for all values of `sub1`).